# ANTLR 4 installation failed on OS X?

Tags: installation, antlr, antlr4

I've got a question about installing ANTLR on my Unix system (MacOS Sierra).

I followed the Quick Start steps ([ANTLR 4 Quick Start installation steps for OS X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5be9.png)) as described on the homepage of ANTLR 4. Everything seems to be working fine but whenever i close my Terminal the export and alias commands seem to have disappeared. Does anyone have an idea what i might be doing wrong? Thank you!

p.s. I'm new to OS X and using the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the `export` and 2 `alias` commands to the `.bash_profile` file in your home directory.

Every time you open a terminal, the contents of that file is loaded.

Comment: Thank you! I need to google how to edit the .bash_profile but i found it.

Answer (score 2):

So the steps i took was as followed;

1. Open terminal
2. enter `cd /usr/local/lib`
3. enter `sudo curl -O http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar`
4. enter `touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile`
5. Text editor opens up.
6. Paste the following;

`export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"`

`alias antlr4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar'`

`alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'`

7. Save the file
8. reopen the terminal. Test if antlr4 and grun works.