# parse code blocks starting and ending with specific keywords

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Following [this question](https://groups.google.com/g/antlr-discussion/c/u58cNQy0lNM/m/pAx6hRefAwAJ), I want to parse blocks of code starting with specific keywords (e.g., `<firstKeyword>`, `<secondKeyword>`, `<thirdKeyword>`, ...) ending with the keyword `End`. In between, some statements should end with either semicolon or a new line. What I have done so far can be seen in [this repository](https://github.com/AltElmer/ElmerSolverParser), but shortly:

```
grammar <garammarName>

// Parser Rules

statement: EndOfStatment;

statement_list: statement+;

section:
    '<firstKeyword>' statement_list End
    | '<secondKeyword>' statement_list End
    | '<thirdKeyword>' statement_list End

sections: section+ EOF;

// Lexer Rules

End: 'End';

NewLine: ('\r'? '\n' | '\n' | '\r') -> skip;

WhiteSpace: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

EndOfStatment: ';' | NewLine;
```

However, the issue is that the TestRig / grun tool ([instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66957247/4999991)) doesn't throw an error when the code blocks are not ended with `End` keyword. For example, the example code `<exampleFile>`:

```
<firstKeyword>
End

<secondKeyword>

<thirdKeyword>
End
```

doesn't return any error with

```
grun <garammarName> sections -tree < <exampleFile>
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me know the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation of the grammar for antlr but isnt it possible that the pipe symbol : | is applied only to the symbols not whole sequences...maybe you need to use some kind of brackets ? Like this: ('<firstKeyword>' statement_list End) | (...) | (...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run input similar to what you've given here, I get:

```
➜ grun ElmerSolver sections -tree  < examples/ex001.sif
line 6:0 missing 'End' at 'Equation'
(sections (section Simulation statement_list End) (section Constants statement_list <missing 'End'>) (section Equation 1 statement_list End) <EOF>)
```

There's specifically an error for a missing 'End' on line 6. (`line 6:0 missing 'End' at 'Equation'`)

ANTLR error recovery does supply the missing 'End' to recover and continue parsing, but it calls out the error.

For reference, this is the full grammar I'm using:

```
grammar ElmerSolver;

// Parser Rules

// eostmt: ';' | CR;

statement: EndOfStatment;

statement_list: statement*;

sections: section+ EOF;
// section: SectionName /* statement_list */ End;

// Lexer Rules

fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
Integer: DIGIT+;

Float:
    [+-]? (DIGIT+ ([.]DIGIT*)? | [.]DIGIT+) ([Ee][+-]? DIGIT+)?;

section:
    'Header' statement_list End                         # headerSection
    | 'Simulation' statement_list End                   # simulatorSection
    | 'Constants' statement_list End                    # constantsSection
    | 'Body' Integer statement_list End                 # bodySection
    | 'Material' Integer statement_list End             # materialSection
    | 'Body Force' Integer statement_list End           # bodyForceSection
    | 'Equation' Integer statement_list End             # equationSection
    | 'Solver' Integer statement_list End               # solverSection
    | 'Boundary Condition' Integer statement_list End   # boundaryConditionSection
    | 'Initial Condition' Integer statement_list End    # initialConditionSection
    | 'Component' Integer statement_list End            # componentSection;

End: 'End';

// statementEnd: ';' NewLine*;

NewLine: ('\r'? '\n' | '\n' | '\r') -> skip;

LineJoining:
    '\\' WhiteSpace? ('\r'? '\n' | '\r' | '\f') -> skip;

WhiteSpace: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

LineComment: '#' ~( '\r' | '\n')* -> skip;

EndOfStatment: ';' | NewLine;
```

((I made your change for the `EndOfStatement` Lexer rule)

And this was the input file I used:

```
Simulation
End

Constants 

Equation 1
End
```

Here's the graphical view I get with the `-gui` grun option;

[image]

---

re: your change with the `EndOfStatment`rule.

EndOfStatment should probably be a parser rule (lowercase).

Also, as your grammar stands, '\n' will always be recognized as a `NewLine` token with a `-> skip` rule to leave it out of the tokenStream.

run the `grun` with a `-tokens` option and you'll see no `EndOfStatement` tokens. (unless you put a ';' in your source file.)

```
➜ grun ElmerSolver sections -tree -tokens < examples/ex001.sif
[@0,0:9='Simulation',<'Simulation'>,1:0]
[@1,11:13='End',<'End'>,2:0]
[@2,16:24='Constants',<'Constants'>,4:0]
[@3,28:35='Equation',<'Equation'>,6:0]
[@4,37:37='1',<Integer>,6:9]
[@5,39:41='End',<'End'>,7:0]
[@6,42:41='<EOF>',<EOF>,7:3]
line 6:0 missing 'End' at 'Equation'
(sections (section Simulation statement_list End) (section Constants statement_list <missing 'End'>) (section Equation 1 statement_list End) <EOF>)
```

If you want the NewLine to be syntactically significant (i.e. you can use it in your grammar),  you'll need to remove the `-> skip`.

However, once you do that, you'll have to be specific about all the places where a NewLine is valid (but I see your LineJoining token so it looks like this is supposed to have a bit of a Python feel, so that might be what you're going for).  (same comment re: `-> skip` applies to this). If you're going down the "Python-like" route, understand that Pythongs EOL and indentation handling is notoriously add for parsers (And "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference" has a section dedicated to what has to be done to handle it).  You could also reference the Python grammar at [ANTLR Python grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python)