# Having issues in initial ANTLR4 setup on macOS Monterrey

Tags: java, macos, installation, antlr4, macos-monterey

I am trying to setup ANTLR4 and I am having issues setting the classpath.
I followed the instructions in the book "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference 2nd Edition", in section "Installing ANTLR", also I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240637/antlr-4-installation-failed-on-os-x/40286537#40286537) and I have not got any results running in command line `antlr4` or `grun` (the alias created).

I am running on a MacbookPro M1, Monterrey. I tried this with java 11 and 8 and the results were the same. I use [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) to handle multiple java versions. Also my default terminal is [oh-my-zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/).

In my bash_profile I added ANTLR configurations like this:
[image]

and in file zshrc I am loading configuration from bash_profile.

This is the output from my terminal.

[image: Output in terminal]

Comment: Why not try the "new way": `pip install antlr4-tools`? antlr.org was just updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kaby76, you are right, it is working with your suggestion. But, I am still trying a way to use it without installing any other prerequisite like python + pip, if I do not find anything I will have to use the  `pip` option. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac OS is gradually locking things down tighter and tighter on the system volume.  While I think there's a good argument that `/usr/local/` shouldn't be a part of that, it looks like it is.

Try placing your antler jar file some place within you home directory (perhaps changing all references to `/usr/local` to just be `~` (or maybe `~/local` if you'd prefer to separate them out.)

I just downloaded the latest:

```
cd ~/lib
sudo curl -O https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar
```

changed by `.zshrc` to reference the new version:

```
export CLASSPATH=".:$HOME/lib/antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"
alias antlr4='java -jar $HOME/lib/antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar'
alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
```

`grun` is running just fine

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Mike Cargal, it makes sense, I tried your suggestion but the error is the same. I moved the file (antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar) into a folder in my local home directory and when I execute `java -jar antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar` the result is: `Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar`, it seems that the problem is with the jar library itself or with my java version or probably I am missing something.

Comment: I've added a bit of detail to my answer, but it doesn't appear that the jar file is corrupt, since it's running here, and I downloaded it with curl.

Comment: I retried and it is working now creating a dedicated _lib_ folder inside my _$HOME_ path. Really thanks for your help.